# how to play same song on two different divs in the HTML using wavesurfer.js in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wavesurfer.js

I want to play same song on 2 different places in the html. I'm using wavesurfer.js to play the song. I want that same song should paly somewhere in the page as well as in the footer of the page. May be something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Player</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row border mt-5">
        <div id="pageDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>




    <footer class="footer bg-secondary border w-100" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="text-white text-center">Footer</p>
                <div id="footerDiv"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>




    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js@5.2.0/dist/wavesurfer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
                container: '#pageDiv , #footerDiv',
                height:48,
                responsive:true,
                hideScrollbar:true,
                waveColor: '#00000078',
                progressColor: '#bbbbbb',
                barRadius:4,
                scrollParent: false
            });
                wavesurfer.load('songs/song1.mp3');
                wavesurfer.on('ready', function(){
                    console.log('ready');
                    wavesurfer.play();
                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I play the same song on two different places. using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: `2 different places in the html` Where is the HTML and relevant js?

Comment: @ikhvjs I have updated the question, can you check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another Instance for another audio.

```js
const wavesurfer1 = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: "#pageDiv"
});

wavesurfer1.load("sample.mp3");

const wavesurfer2 = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: "#footerDiv",
});

wavesurfer2.load("sample.mp3");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row border mt-5">
        <div id="pageDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer bg-secondary border w-100" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="text-white text-center">Footer</p>
            <div id="footerDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: in this way both will play & pause synchronously?

Comment: @Qadeer, you can control when to play or pause for each instance.